# where to put ActiveModel::Validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activemodel

I try to follow http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html , but where should I put the

```
 class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
      if some_complex_logic
        record.errors[:base] = "This record is invalid"
      end
    end

    private
      def some_complex_logic
        # ...
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[This guy](http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/) puts them under `app/validators/`, which I've done as well, ever since I saw that blog post.

Comment: Any chance anyone knows how to display this folder in "Project" structure in Netbeans? I'm currently only able to access this folder through "Files", but i hate the tree hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Add this class in your lib directory and require it in your model and include it inside.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also add it to the models directory of your app. Also, as mentioned by shingara, you need to add,

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
validates_with MyValidator
```

to the model file of the record class.